# How can I get an element that is visible after scrolling using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to load a webpage using Puppeteer, scroll down some number of pixels, and then get the uppermost element that is visible. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do this?

Note that I have zero selectors or classes.  I don't know which element I want.

Also, there are *many* questions about determining whether or not an element is visible.  This is *not* what I am asking.

Comment: Can you share an URL where you need this usecase?

Comment: provide some html , you an get the visible elements by using `{visible:true} `  in your selection

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher I need it on arbitrary websites.